# BAT file to Open .SQL files in order and paste append to TXT file in turn

Tags: batch-file, copy, paste

I am trying to create a BAT file which opens up .SQL outputs in turn (labelled 01. 02. etc) copies the contents and appends the contents into a TXT file, then closes the .SQL file again. I can figure out how to open up all SQL files at once, but that isn't what I'm trying to achieve.

Here is what I've already tried:
`for %%l IN ("C:\BAT TEST 26092019"\*.sql) do start "" "%%l"`

This opens up ALL .SQL files at once. Not what I'm looking for.

This creates the TXT file from scratch...it's the next bit I'm trying to answer.

```
@ECHO OFF
cd "C:\BAT TEST 26092019"
dir > "merge.txt"
copy /y nul merge.txt
```

Comment: If you don't want them to all open at once, either try `Start`'s `/Wait` option, or remove `start ""`  altogether.

Comment: Incidentally, is `Copy "C:\BAT TEST 26092019\*.sql">"C:\BAT TEST 26092019\merge.txt"` or `Type "C:\BAT TEST 26092019\*.sql">"C:\BAT TEST 26092019\merge.txt"` what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying these options now, thanks for getting back. Will update shortly.

Comment: Type "C:\BAT TEST 26092019\*.sql">"C:\BAT TEST 26092019\merge.txt" almost works. It opens and copies the text from the first .SQL file and copies it into the MERGE file 3 times, rather than copying the contents of all three and copying them in once in turn - progress though.

Comment: Correction - it DOES work. I just need a line break to go into the merge.txt file with each append and then it will line up perfectly. Thanks for your help!